# Bounty score styling needs to be fixed in Reputation tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty, profile-page

When I open **reputation tab** in **user profile** where he/she got bounty then the **bounty score** is showing in gray color which should be in white color
[image]

This is happening in **Reputation -> Post** tab

Now when you see that bounty score in **Reputation -> Time** tab then it looks fine.

[image]

Screenshot for tabs:

[image]

Comment: I think different colors are set for the total reputation gain (gray) on a post and individual reputation gain(white). it may be set on purpose and not a bug.

Comment: It could be, but it is not clearly visible

Comment: This has been fixed.